# Link Microsoft Account

Tags: php, mysql, xbox360

## Microsoft Account

I've been looking for a few hours and come to find **NO** results.
I'm looking for a way to link ***Xbox360*** Accounts to a players profile on my website. I would like to use the Microsoft login to make it legitimate. This way players can't just add random ***live accounts*** to their website account.

## Usage

1. Link XboxLive account to their website account for legitimate use and validation.
2. Other players can view their profile and see the linked Microsoft account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately there is currently no publicly available way to do this. It can only be done if you're a registered developer, in which case you should refer to the documentation on http://developer.xboxlive.com/.